# Alternative solution to browser reading the contents of local file system

Tags: javascript, browser, cross-browser, cross-domain

I absolutely understand that Browser cannot read the contents of the local file. But my client still has following requirements that I need to cater:
1). There is an installer that will create a folder with bunch of HTML and JS files. The HTML files will refer to the JS files using  tag.
2). The web application (running through http:/localhost/) will have a link, which on click will read the required HTML file.

I am aware that one approach could be using ActiveXObject, but that would be IE specific.
Is there any alternative approach that you can assist me with? Or should I respond that no solution exists for such kind of scenario?

Comment: You seem to be using `http:` and not `file:` to load your local files through a local server so I don't see what the problem is?

Comment: @Paul: The web application is a third party application, and it can only be accessed via http: